# Web service migration from Local IIS to Azure

Tags: azure, iis, cloud, azure-web-app-service, data-migration

I Used Azure Website Migration Assistance to migrate my web service that was running on my Local VM's IIS. My Migration process was successful and also I was able to use this web service. But I can't find where to find the migrated source code in azure portal. All I can see is some 20Mb of data in on the dashboard graph of azure portal. If I need to changed some of my code where to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is on the Azure Web App should now match what was on your IIS server. Now, to update the web app, you can use the deployment techniques here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/

The simplest method to deploy to check what content is on your web app would be to use the SCM site. This is available at: https://your-site-name.scm.azurewebsites.net. Go to Debug Console > CMD and then the site > wwwroot folder to see your web app content. You can also upload to the site via drag and drop.

[image: Kudu SCM site]

Alternatively, you can download the publishing settings for your web app via the portal and then re-use the migration tool, select the site, and then upload the publishing settings. However I would suggest using the deployment techniques above first. (Disclaimer: I wrote the migration tool.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to push changes to your Azure Website/Web App.  They are listed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/

One simple way is to use an FTP client like FileZilla.  In the classic portal, you will find the FTP address (hostname) and the credentials in the dashboard tab.  In the new portal, select your Web App and the FTP address will be displayed in the Essentials section at the top of the page.  Click on Settings and Deployment credentials to set your FTP user password.

Another simple alternative is to use Dropbox.  Take a look at this video for how to set instructions: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Tutorials/Dropbox-Deployment-to-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites